# How can I view a text file I've just created using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I know how to create a text file using [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) which is shown below:

```
Dim a As New FileSystemObject
Set Text = a.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\test.txt")
```

Now I want some script so that my this `test.txt` file just opens in front of my monitor. Because I know that when we make an Excel file, we just use

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
```

When used the Excel sheet is created and just opens up in front of us. In a similar way I had tried for text file but it's not at all working.

What would be a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use WScript.Shell's Run method to launch documents in their associated editor:

```
Dim a As New FileSystemObject
Set Text = a.CreateTextFile("C:\Folder\test.txt")

Dim wsh
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wsh.Run "C:\Folder\test.txt"
```

Comment: There should be a little check-mark under the voting arrows to the left of this answer, just click that :)

Comment: Kim,its done.Can u just suggest me some link where i could learn vbscripts with test complete tool as i started working on this some weeks back.??

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't know anything about Test Complete.

Comment: Kim,anything related to advanced vbscripting e books??

Comment: It's been years since I did any VBScript, and learned all of it through experimentation and through online samples, so unfortunately I don't have any more references for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open your file using an another editor other than the one associated do:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("notepad c:\path\file.txt")
```