# Physically opening a text file

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file `C:\user\test.txt` with the text "This is a test", and I want to physically open the file using VBScript (as if i were to click *Accesories → Notepad*). I want to see the file open on my screen so I can visually read the text.

Now, for some reason I can't. This is what I'm trying (I tried with and without the "textfile.close" line, and yes, the file exists in that path):

```
dim FS1, textfile

Const ForReading = 1 

set FS1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set textfile = FS1.OpenTextFile("C:\user\test.txt", ForReading, True)
textfile.close
```

What am I missing? I have no issue creating, writing, or appending... but I just can't open it!

Comment: Not to be crass, but there is no such thing as physically opening a file. What you describe would be launching or starting notepad.exe and specifying the file you are interested in viewing. Try searching on the text "launch notepad vbscript" and you should have your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view a text file I've just created using VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157979/how-can-i-view-a-text-file-ive-just-created-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the file in Notepad:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "notepad.exe c:\user\test.txt"
End With
```

You can also just *run the file* and it will open in your default `txt` editor (whatever Windows file association you have established for extension `txt`).

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "c:\user\test.txt"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Bond, this did exactly what i had in mind (y)

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the file?

You should be  doing  something like

```
' Open the file for input.
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

' Read from the file and display the results.
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
    Document.Write TextLine & "<br />"
Loop
MyFile.Close
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Thanks Bruce, this work perfectly displaying the contents of my file.